# find all the elements with equal counts with Counter().most_common

Tags: python, collections, counter

I am using Counter().most_common from collections. My input(e.g counter_list) has many equal elements but if i use Counter(mylist).most_common(1) instead of getting all the results i get only the first

`mylist=['gene0.txt','gene1.txt','gene1.txt','gene2.txt','gene2.txt','gene3.txt','gene3.txt']`
`C = Counter(mylist).most_common(1)`
   I am getting this
`[('gene1.txt',2)]`
Instead of that
`[('gene1.txt',2),('gene2.txt',2),('gene3.txt',2)]`

Comment: Try ```C = Counter(mylist).most_common()``` instead

Comment: I did it. It prints the whole list with the least values inside (in that case blah0,1) i want only the elements with the highest value (2)

Comment: Can you update your question to include ```mylist```?

Comment: of course... done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
mylist=['gene0.txt','gene1.txt','gene1.txt','gene2.txt','gene2.txt','gene3.txt','gene3.txt']

from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

c = Counter(mylist)
print(list(takewhile(lambda val: val[1] == c.most_common(1)[0][1], c.most_common())))
```

Prints:

```
[('gene1.txt', 2), ('gene2.txt', 2), ('gene3.txt', 2)]
```

---

Or without `itertools.takewhile`, using list comprehension:

```
print([item for item in c.most_common() if item[1] == c.most_common(1)[0][1]])
```

But this will iterate over all items in `most_common()`.

---

EDIT (Some debug info for clarity):

```
for val in c.most_common():
    print('val[0]={} val[1]={} c.most_common(1)[0][1]={}'.format(val[0], val[1], c.most_common(1)[0][1]))
```

Prints:

```
val[0]=gene1.txt val[1]=2 c.most_common(1)[0][1]=2
val[0]=gene2.txt val[1]=2 c.most_common(1)[0][1]=2
val[0]=gene3.txt val[1]=2 c.most_common(1)[0][1]=2
val[0]=gene0.txt val[1]=1 c.most_common(1)[0][1]=2
```

Comment: it works... I don't know how (I have some study to do) but it works....
<3<3<3<3 thank you

Comment: can you please show me a way to find info about the build of lambda you wrote?

Comment: @MikeEugeniou `lambda val: val[1] == c.most_common(1)[0][1]`. `val` is item from `most_common()` call -> tuple `(value, count)`. So `val[1]` is count and `c.most_common(1)[0][1]` is most common count found in our `Counter`. We take only values that have this count value.

Comment: what the difference between val[1] and val[0] i can see the correlation with the c.most_common(1)[0][1]. (when I write val[0] and c.most_common(1)[0][0] it gives only the first occurrence) but how it works?

Comment: @MikeEugeniou `val[1]` is count and `val[0]` is the value that is counted. I would suggest making a loop `for val in c.most_common():` and print the `val` to see what it holds.

Comment: so the c.most_common(1)[0][1] is the index of the tuple to check if val and c.most_common(1) has the same values

Comment: @MikeEugeniou I edited my answer with some debug info. There you see that `c.most_common(1)[0][1]` is equal to `2`, that's the most common count found in our Counter.